# EXCEL OFFSET formula with rows input as array

Tags: arrays, excel, offset

Does Excel's OFFSET() really not allow for array inputs on rows or col ? or am I just missing/not seeing something banal ?

[image]

{1\2} would be my expected result

Comment: It does work, but the resulting array cannot be easily used and can't really be output to cells without a helper function like `N()`

Comment: Use index instead.

Comment: @Harun24hr this was just a simplification of a more complex formula where i cant use index - thanks anyway

Comment: @Rory is there another helper that check automatically for text and numbers - combining T() and N() ? to avoid IF(T()="";N();T())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED using N() around result - T() if result is text - if both ive used this: IF(T()="";N();T())

NEW PROBLEM:

(works if E1 is just a number instead of an array)

[image]

expected result: {2;4;6;8;10\12;14;16;18;20}

anyone?

Comment: `=FILTER(CELL("contents",OFFSET(B3:B12,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B12),,0),E1#)),A3:A12="b")`, though I'm not sure why you're not just using `=FILTER(B3:C12,A3:A12="b")`.

Comment: You really shouldn't be posting another question as an answer.

Comment: @Rory yeah I know but they are related problems

Comment: @JosWoolley thanks I was missing that CELL() - this was a simplification of a more complex formula where I can't use your second more simple solution

Comment: what type of result you get from that OFFSET() that can't be automatically spilled into cells ? is there some documentation on that ?